# Remote Desktop connection getting black from ubuntu 13

Tags: windows, xrdp, remote-login

I have installed **xrdp** in Ubuntu and while I try to connect the remote desktop from Windows 7 to the Ubuntu machine, the session is being connected but all I am seeing is a full black screen.

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose `ubuntu-2d` as the dafault session when connecting from Xrdp.

To do that:

```
cd /home/user
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

Comment: Hi i do the following setting as you given but i still getting the blackscreen error